# kafka-reassign-partition.sh no longer accepts log_dirs parameter

Tags: apache-kafka

I had some issues with my Kafka (v. 2.5.0) cluster over the weekend.  Several drives filled up due to sudden data surges for their topics, and additionally a drive failed on one broker.  It was quite the confluence, and comedy, of errors.  Luckily I had enough capacity that my topic replication was robust enough to prevent any data loss, but I had to shift a lot of topic partitions around to balance out the disk usage.  I have 6 brokers each with 12 data drives (`/data01` through `/data12`).  The `log.dirs` property of each broker is

```
log.dirs=/data01/logs,/data02/logs,/data03/logs,/data04/logs,/data05/logs,/data06/logs,/data07/logs,/data08/logs,/data09/logs,/data10/logs,/data11/logs,/data12/logs
```

I was able to move some partitions around with `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` and its `log_dirs` option, which let me move specific partitions to specific disks using a JSON file like

```
{ "partitions":
  [
    {
      "topic":"insights-facts",
      "partition":30,
      "replicas":[12,7,11],
      "log_dirs":["/data01/logs/insights-facts-30", "/data11/logs/insights-facts-30", "/data07/logs/insights-facts-30"]
    }
  ],
  "version":1
}
```

At some point, however, something happened to my cluster, and now I'm unable to use the `log_dirs` option to any success.  I get this error message when I try to use an absolute path as the `log_dirs` value:

```
Partitions reassignment failed due to Failed to alter dir for insights-facts-30-12
kafka.common.AdminCommandFailedException: Failed to alter dir for insights-facts-30-12
        at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand.$anonfun$alterReplicaLogDirsIgnoreReplicaNotAvailable$1(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:610)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
        at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand.alterReplicaLogDirsIgnoreReplicaNotAvailable(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:602)
        at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand.reassignPartitions(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:632)
        at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$.executeAssignment(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:221)
        at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$.executeAssignment(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:205)
        at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$.main(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:65)
        at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand.main(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.LogDirNotFoundException: The user-specified log directory is not found in the broker config.
```

Per the docs, if I use "any" as the absolute path, the partition will move brokers successfully, but it will randomly pick a disk to use.  I have verified the paths I'm trying to move to actually exist, except the last directory which Kafka wants to create itself.

Things I've already tried, to no avail:

- restarting the brokers hosting the partitions in question
- restarting my entire zookeeper cluster
- restarting the controller broker
- doing a rolling restart of all my brokers

Any ideas how to resolve this error?  The most frustrating thing is that it used to work, and I don't know what changed to make it not work anymore.

Comment: Can you show the log_dirs configuration in the broker.properties of the brokers 7, 11, and 12?

Comment: @mike sure.  I've edited the question to include them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's still relevant but your JSON file looks wrong. Remove the /(topic)-(partition) part from the log_dirs array in order to have directories matching the ones in your server.properties. This is pretty much what the error massage is telling you.
It should look like that :

```
{
 "version":1, 
 "partitions":
  [
    {
      "topic":"insights-facts",
      "partition":30,
      "replicas":[12,7,11],
      "log_dirs":["/data01/logs", "/data11/logs", "/data07/logs"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as the correct answer. While I no longer have the original problem, I had a similar problem and the JSON snippet you provided Just Worked™ so I'm assuming it was also spot-on for my previous issue.